# 【Android】動的に追加したViewの位置を取得したい｡

Tags: android, android-layout

例えば以下のようにしてXMLで定義されたView(`content`)があります｡そこに子Viewとして`contentItem`を8個追加します｡

```java
final LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.content_list);
for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
  LinearLayout contentItem = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.general_item, null);
  content.addView(contentItem);
}
```

これのそれぞれの､Viewつまり､`content`の子View(`contentItem`)の位置を取得する方法を知りたいです｡
`onViewCreated`で以下のように`getLocationInWindow`を使ったのですが､すべての値が0のなってしまいました｡

```java
    private final int[] viewPosition = new int[8];
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle bundle){
        LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.content_list);
        for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
            final int [] anchorPos = new int[2];
            View contentView = content.getChildAt(i);
            contentView.getLocationInWindow(anchorPos);
            viewPosition[i] = anchorPos[1];
        }
    }
```

他になにか方法はありますか?  もしあれば教えて下さい｡  よろしくおねがいします｡

**追記:**

何をやりたいのかというと､http://doruby.kbmj.com/daoka_tips/20120417/Android_ScrollView_このサイトに書かれている､`ObservableScrollView`というものを使うとScrollViewの位置がわかるようなので､Viewの位置を調べて､その位置で特定の処理を行うということをしたいです｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getLocationInWindow`を使いたいのでしたら、そのコードでは動きません。
というのも、`onViewCreated`の段階では、レイアウト計算が終わっていないためです。

レイアウト計算が終わった後、改めて取得する必要があります。レイアウト計算の終了通知は
`addOnGlobalLayoutListener`で受け取れます。そのとき取得すれば、値がとれます。

このリスナは、レイアウト計算が終了したらいつでも呼ばれますので、不要になったら`removeOnGlobalLayoutListener`で、削除するとよいでしょう。

御武運を。

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayout`の`indexOfChild(View)`でしょうか？

http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#indexOfChild(android.view.View)

追記

レイアウト位置を知りたいということだったので、子Viewの`onLayout()`を拾うというのはどうでしょうか？

http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)

Comment: さん
回答ありがとうございます｡  しかし､質問の意図が少し違うように思われます｡  Viewの相対的な位置が知りたいのではなく､絶対的な位置を知りたいのです｡ つまり､そのViewがLayout内のどこにあるのかを知りたいのです｡
わかりづらい表現をしてしまい申し訳ありません｡  もう少し詳細を記述します｡

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます｡  それをするには`LinearLayout`を継承して`onLayout`をオーバーライドするということでしょうか?  もう少し詳しく教えていただけますか｡

Comment: オーバーライドするのは、`LinearLayout`ではなく、子供のViewです。

Comment: 子のViewつまり‘contentItem‘なのでLinearLayoutではないのですか?